# Highlight text on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, highlight

I want to make animation highlighting each letter of the text. Is there jQuery plugin to highlight text on window scoll? Trying to figure out the lightweight way to achieve this.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean.Highlight all text on scroll ? or just one row at a time or what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because asking for 3rd resources is off topic on SO

Comment: i mean to highlight phrase on page by wrapping it in span.

Comment: add onscroll, detect distance, do some calculation to figure out what letter, add some CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I wanted to make:

```
highlight();

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  highlight();
});

function highlight(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height = $(window).height();

  $(".highlight").each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    if (scroll+height >= pos) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    } 
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vm1sht5/3/